# how to centralize the error message in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project which uses react-toast-notifications I want to centralize all error cases in a separate file and try to call it directly in the catch block

```js
    const Index = () => {
      const { addToast } = useToasts();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchDataFromApi()
          .then(data => ...)
          .catch(error => call centralize error file to display toast)
      }, [])
    
      //...
    }
```

Comment: I think you can just export the function that handles errors from the centralized file and just invoke it inside the catch block.

Comment: how I can do it with a function that calls the toast your any idea thank you